# How does re instantiating work for this scenario?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I am using Java

```
public class MapsConfusion {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap< Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
      ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
      lst.add("something");
      lst.add("something2");
      map.put(i, lst);
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
      System.out.println(map.get(j));
    }   
  }  
}
```

The way this works is, it creates a **new** arraylist each time it loops around. Here is my question,

**Thinking about pointers**, when you declare a new `Arraylist<>` each time, you are creating a **new** `Arraylist` at a new address am I correct?

**Other question:** Doesn't the list only exist within the scope, which is the `for loop?` Then how is is**still** accessible when I do the other (last) for loop?

Comment: Now you have 5 answers to your question, consider accepting one or comment what's missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1 Question

Yes, you always create a new object and therefore a new address.

See this for further information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

## 2 Question

The ArrayList exists as long as at least one variable pointing at it. In this case as long as `map` exists and the main method runs.

Here's more about the life cycle of an object: http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/the-life-cycle-of-a-java-object/

Comment: so in general, if I define something in a local scope, but outside the scope something points to that item, that item (one in local scope) still exists?

Comment: Yes, as long as any variable points at an object it stays alive. If not, the Java GarbageCollector removes it at some time (frees the space). https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/

Answer (score 2):

> when you declare a new Arraylist<> each time, you are creating a new
>   Arraylist at a new address am I correct?

Yes you are right. Each `ArrayList`is created at a new memory location.

> Doesn't the list only exist within the scope, which is the for loop?
>   Then how is is still accessible when I do the other (last) for loop?

It's accessible because each newly created `ArrayList` gets added in to your `map` and that's why you do not lose it when your first `for loop` ends.

If you do not add each newly created `ArrayList` in your `map`, you won't be able to access any `ArrayList` outside the first `for-loop` in which it is created.

Answer (score 1):

> Thinking about pointers, when you declare a new Arraylist<> each time,
>   you are creating a new Arraylist at a new address am I correct?

Correct.

> Doesn't the list only exist within the scope, which is the for loop?
>   Then how is is still accessible when I do the other (last) for loop?

An object is automatically deallocated by the garbage collector only when there are no references pointing to it. In your case the list is added in `map`, therefore it is not deallocated since there is an element of `map` pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Thinking about pointers, when you declare a new Arraylist<> each time,
>   you are creating a new Arraylist at a new address am I correct?

Yes you are correct the pointer to the List **lst** only exists in the scope of the first loop.

> Other question: Doesn't the list only exist within the scope, which is
>   the for loop? Then how is isstill accessible when I do the other
>   (last) for loop?

But you assigned the object the pointer **lst** was pointing to, into the Map **map** outside the looop. Therefore the object still exists because the mapentry is pointing to it.

If you move the Map also into the first loop you will get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not removed all references to the arrayList, it will still exist and remain accessible after the first for loop. The fundamental difference is:

- the arrayList won't be accessible by any variable/pointers which you have declared within the for loop, as those variables are within the scope of the first for loop only.
- During the run of the first for loop, you have pointed the hashmap's value entry to each individual list and apparently the hashmap is accessible beyond the scope of the for loop.

  Converging from the above two points, all arrayLists are accessible from references made in HashMap's value